# Ruby Haml - cuts out tag (&& ||) attributes

Tags: ruby, haml

**Strange behaviour of haml - it cuts out tag attributes.**

for example, i write two ways:

first - head inside layout:

```
!!!
%html{ lang: I18n.locale }
  %head{ 'data-hook' => 'inside_head' }
    %title= "sample title"
    %meta{ content: 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'http-equiv' => 'Content-Type' }
```

it produce next code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head data-hook="inside_head">
    <title>    sample title
</title>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
```

if not look on identation, all is fine, but if i write head in partial and render it, haml cuts out head tag, but passing content of partial!
code, my second and preffered way is:

```
!!!
%html{ lang: I18n.locale }
  = render 'shared/head', title: "sample app"
```

and partial in shared/head.haml:

```
%head{ 'data-hook' => 'inside_head' }
  %title= title
  %meta{ content: 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'http-equiv' => 'Content-Type' }
```

but, haml produce next strange code, tag 'head' is missed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <body>

  <title>  sample app
</title>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
```

What i doing wrong? Or Haml is buggy?

See my layout file:
[image]

See my head file:
[image]

See result html:
[image]

Comment: Is this Rails? When rendering partials, Rails will look for a filename with a leading underscore, i.e. in this case the file will be `shared/_head.haml`, not `shared/head.haml`. Do you have such a file as well. If it has different contents it may explain what you are seeing.

Comment: yes, of course. file name is exactle _head.haml and i call it as render 'shared/head'. this is so commonplace.

Comment: so you get `<body>` instead of `<head>` - strange

Comment: yes, yes. Problem still here.

Answer (score 1):

Try to rename `_head.haml` to `_head.html.haml`. Works for me.
So the final usage will be the same:

```
!!!
%html
  = render 'shared/head'
```

And btw haml has better way to pass attributes for haml tags:

```
%head(data-hook='inside_head')
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, Yuri! I'm tryin to rename, but nothing change - head yet dissapeared.

Comment: maybe it happend because you don't have %body in your view. You need to try something like:
`!!!
%html
  = render 'head'
  %body`